# Fixed element-UI table size when column changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I make a Element-UI table and use v-if to control column show/hide. It works perfectly, but a little problem.

The table will change size by itself when column is show/hide. I already fixed width and height in the table attribute, but seems not to work.

Why do the table change size, and how to fixed size?

Thank you.

In the following code, this is an easy sample.

```js
var Main = {
    methods: {
      show(num) {
        if(num == 1){
          this.show1 = !this.show1;
        }
        if(num == 2){
          this.show2 = !this.show2;
        }
        if(num == 3){
          this.show3 = !this.show3;
        }
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        show1: true,
        show2: true,
        show3: true,
        tableData:  [{
          date: '2016-05-03',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-02',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-01',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }]
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
.el-table td{
    background: #F2F6FC;
 }
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
  <el-button type="success" @click="show(1)">Show/Hide Date</el-button>
  <el-button type="success" @click="show(2)">Show/Hide Name</el-button>
  <el-button type="success" @click="show(3)">Show/Hide Address</el-button>
  <el-table
    :data="tableData"
    style="width: 600px"
    height = 300>
    <el-table-column
      v-if = "show1"
      prop="date"
      label="Date"
      width="250">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      v-if = "show2"
      prop="name"
      label="Name"
      width="250">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      v-if = "show3"
      prop="address"
      label="Address"
      width="300">
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
</template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to [Halil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58976888/5296404), I noticed a resizing problem on the height, while using `height` to set a fixed height, and when modifying the `columns` used in a `v-for`.

As a workaround, setting `max-height` instead of `height` worked for me.

The origin may be the same than this one.

My sample code:

```
<el-table
  :data="table"
  :default-sort="{ prop: 'foo' }"
  :max-height="600"
>
  <el-table-column
    v-for="col in columns"
    :key="col.prop"
    :prop="col.prop"
    :label="col.label"
    :width="col.width"
    sortable
    :sort-method="(a, b) => sortTableColumn(a, b, col.prop)"
  />
</el-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `v-if` to make it fixed size. Change the style of target element like `visibility: hidden` instead of using `v-if`. When you use `v-if`, it removes the element on DOM, that's why your table`s size changes. This is a nasty solution but this is the fastest way to do this.

An example

```
<el-table-column
   style = "{ visibility: show1 ? 'hidden' : 'visible' }"
   prop="date"
   label="Date"
   width="250">
</el-table-column>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to use visibility to show/hide column, it's worked, but it leaves a white block. Is it possible to align left when middle column hide?

Comment: @J.SLee did you figure this out? :)

Comment: Element UI table as of the moment has a bug. V-show doesnt work on el-table-column only v-if works, its not yet fixed tho its still an open issue in their github issues page.